# Modify dependency gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, dependencies, rvm

I have a big project in Rails which depends on many third party gems. One of these gems is a gem developed by me and is hosted on Github.

Now, if I clone the big Rails project and I need to modify something in my "home made" gem, what should I do? I use RVM, if that helps.

For Pythonists, what I need is something similar to the `-e` flag in `pip`, where you can install dependencies as editable, so that you can modify them and view the actual changes in the package that requires them.

Answer (score 3):

You can just checkout your gem locally and edit it as you wish.

In your rails project `Gemfile` point to the local checkout of the gem:

```
gem 'your_gem_name', path: '../your_gem_name'
```

Answer (score 1):

To make some changes in the gem you have just to create a brunch in the gem, and then point the branch inside the **Gemfile** of the Rails project to the gem branch, for example:

```
gem 'your-gem', :git => 'https://github.com/you/your-gem.git', :branch => 'new-project-branch'
```

More docs on definition you can find on [bundler doc page](http://bundler.io/v1.3/gemfile.html).

**NOTE:** Of course you can use `:path` key instead of `git` or `github` keys in case you have simultaneoues development phase over both your gem, and Rails project, but this trick is invalid for publishing the rails project to the web (like [heroku](/questions/tagged/heroku), etc).

Answer (score 1):

[Bundler 1.1 or above](http://bundler.io/v1.2/git.html) accepts [`:github`](http://hashnuke.com/2012/06/05/bundler-new-github-option.html) as option. So you can just say:

```
gem 'gem_name', :github => 'github_username/gem_name'
```

and even better when you can mention which ref, branch, or tag to look for code in your repository:

```
gem 'gem_name', :github => 'github_username/gem_name', :branch => "stable-branch"
```

Now, you can independently work on your github repositories and push the code to specified branches as mentioned on your project's Gemfile.

But, you might want to work and test on your local so you can do something like this:

```
if ENV['RAILS_ENV'] == 'production'
  gem 'gem_name', :github => 'github_username/gem_name', :branch => "stable"
else
  gem 'gem_name', :path => "/path/to/gem_name", :branch => 'test'
end
```

Comment: So basically I need to modify my project's Gemfile. I thought there would be a way to tell Bundler to install a gem in editable mode, just like you would tell Pip to do so.